# Hide other other applications icon?

Tags: android

I want to hide few apps icon from my application. This is my code, but it's not working:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.test.android.app", "com.test.android.app.launcher homeactivity"); 
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-24452
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=19832, uid=10158, package uid=10143
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting(IPackageManager.java:2573)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1250)
at com.example.dashboard.MainActivity.getAllpackages(MainActivity.java:169)
at com.example.dashboard.MainActivity.initListview(MainActivity.java:77)
at com.example.dashboard.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:76)
at com.example.dashboard.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:66)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the manifest.xml you will add

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

At the Android.mk will add

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```

Comment: yes i did add this permission but problem is remain same

Comment: for this i have to configure ndk i think because ndk is using android.mk file

Comment: and i did try this to its not working i did search and then find this way but its not working

Comment: Try this PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT instead PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64459/discussion-between-rit-and-hafiz-m-usman).